# Sphinx Pygments lexer filter extension?

Tags: python-sphinx, pygments

I have a Lisp-like language I would like to highlight using Pygments in Sphinx code snippet documentation.  My approach is to extend the existing CommonLispLexer to add the built-in names using a NameHighlightFilter.  However, it is not working, so I must be missing something obvious.  I have added the following to my conf.py:

```
def setup(app): 
    from sphinx.highlighting import lexers
    from pygments.lexers import CommonLispLexer
    from pygments.token import Name
    from pygments.filters import NameHighlightFilter
    tl_lexer = CommonLispLexer()
    tl_lexer.add_filter(NameHighlightFilter(
            names=['define-function', 'define-macro', 
                   'define-variable', 'define-constant'],
            tokentype=Name.Builtin,
            ))
    app.add_lexer('tl', tl_lexer)

highlight_language = 'tl'
```

But the NameHighlightFilter has no effect.  Code blocks are highlighted as if they were Lisp, but my new builtin names have no special highlighting.

Comment: Running this code in an interactive Python session confirms that the filter is not working as I intend.  Even after calling `add_filter` as above, define-function is still tokenized as a `Name.Variable`, not a `Name.Builtin`.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the `NameHighlighFilter` only converts tokens that the lexer categorizes as `Token.Name`, but the `CommonLispLexer` categorizes almost everything as `Name.Variable`. This is the filter function of the `NameHighlightFilter`, from the Pygments source code:

```
def filter(self, lexer, stream):
    for ttype, value in stream:
        if ttype is Name and value in self.names:
            yield self.tokentype, value
        else:
            yield ttype, value
```

My only workaround was to write my own filter. This function gave me the look I wanted.

```
def filter(self, lexer, stream):
    define = False
    for ttype, value in stream:
        if value in self.tl_toplevel_forms:
            ttype = Name.Builtin
            define = True
        elif define and ttype == Name.Variable:
            define = False
            ttype = Name.Function
        elif value in self.tl_special_forms:
            ttype = Name.Variable
        # the Common Lisp lexer highlights everything else as
        # variables, which isn't the look I want.  Instead
        # highlight all non-special things as text.
        elif ttype == Name.Variable:
            ttype = Name.Text
        yield ttype, value
```

As a note to Pygments developers, perhaps the `NameHighlightFilter` could take an optional argument representing the token type(s) to be converted (currently it only takes the output token type).